# Composer can not install dependencies

Tags: composer-php, mbstring

I have a FuelPhp project and i am trying to install dependencies via composer.
When i ran composer install on command line, i get following error;

```
 The requested PHP extension ext-mbstring ^0.0.0 has the wrong version (7.0.18) installed. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
```

I have mbstring extension installed and enabled. Why composer complaining about ext-mbstring extension ?[image]

Composer Version:1.6.3
Php Version:7.0.18
OS:Windows 10

This is from composer.json

```
   "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "composer/installers": "~1.0",
    "fuel/docs": "dev-1.7/master",
    "fuel/core": "dev-1.7/master",
    "fuel/auth": "dev-1.7/master",
    "fuel/email": "dev-1.7/master",
    "fuel/oil": "dev-1.7/master",
    "fuel/orm": "dev-1.7/master",
    "fuel/parser": "dev-1.7/master",
    "trait-orm-format": "dev-master",
    "fuelphp/upload": "2.0.2",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.5.*",
    "michelf/php-markdown": "1.4.0",
    "ext-mbstring": "^0.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^0.0.0` version constraint means Composer will not install anything beyond `0.0.*` version.

Use `"ext-mbstring": "*"` as version constraint and install should pass correctly.